# How to split this date from "dd/mm/yyyy" to "yyyy/mm/dd"?

Tags: javascript, html

How to split from `dd/mm/yyyy` to `yyyy/mm/dd`?

My HTML:

```html
<form>
<div class="nativeDatePicker">
<input type="date" id="bday" name="bday" placeholder="Pilih Tanggal">
</div>
</form>
```

My JavaScript:

```js
var nativePicker=document.querySelector('.nativeDatePicker');
var fallbackPicker = document.querySelector('.fallbackDatePicker');
var fallbackLabel = document.querySelector('.fallbackLabel');

fallbackPicker.style.display = 'none';
fallbackLabel.style.display = 'none';

var test = document.createElement('input');
test.type = 'date';

if (test.type === 'text') {
    nativePicker.style.display = 'none';
    fallbackPicker.style.display = 'block';
    fallbackLabel.style.display = 'block';

    populateDays(monthSelect.value);
    populateYears();
}
```

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this $("#bday").datepicker({ format:'yyyy-mm-dd'});

Answer (score 2):

You can split the date and then again join it by the required delimiter

```js
function getDate() {
  let date = document.getElementById('bday').value;
  let nd = date.split('-').join('/')
  console.log(nd);
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="bday" name="bday" placeholder="Pilih Tanggal">
<button onclick='getDate()'>Get Date</button>
```

In your case if the current date format is `dd/mm/yyyy` split the date by  `/` then reverse the array and join it by `/`

```
let dt = dt.split('/').reverse().join('/')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a more sustainable solution, you would use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

with this lib you could do something like:

```js
var date = moment("01/05/2019", "DD/mm/YYYY");
var result = date.format("YYYY/mm/DD");
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
function convertDDMMYYYY2YYYYMMDD(pDate1)
{
    var sDate1 = pDate1;//'15/01/2019';
    var sDate2 = '';

    var aDate1 = sDate1.split('/');

    for (var i=aDate1.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {   
        if (i!=aDate1.length-1)
            sDate2 += "/";

        sDate2 += aDate1[i];
    }

    return sDate2;
}

alert(convertDDMMYYYY2YYYYMMDD('15/01/2019'));
```